# How do I allow uppercase and lowercase user input?

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie C++ programmer. I've written a basic emotion checker that reacts based on your reply that gets fetched from an array. I'm wondering how to make it so that the replies work in both upper and lower case when typed in? E.g. when the user types in "happy" or "Happy" both would work. I've read about switch statements and toupper/tolower but I'm lost on how to implement these for my code. Here it is:

```
// Array of emotions

string positive[] = {"happy", "pleased", "joyful", "excited", "content", "cheerful", "satisfied", "positive"};
string negative[] = {"unhappy", "sad", "depressed", "gloomy", "down", "glum", "despair", "negative"};

string reply;

cout << "Please state your current emotions." << endl;
cin >> reply;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

if (reply == positive[i])
{
        cout << "I am glad to hear that!" << endl;
}

else if (reply == negative[i])
{
    cout << "I am sorry to hear that." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Convert all input to lower case before entering your loop.

Comment: check [tolower](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/) on documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to add a step in to process the string `reply` after reading it in.

One solution would be to iterate over the length of `reply` and call `tolower` on each character in the string.

An example modified from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/

```
int i = 0;
while (reply[i]) {
    c=reply[i];
    reply[i] = tolower(c);
    i++;
}
```

Then when you compare the strings you don't need to worry about case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, write a function named equals to compare two world is the same or not by convert all character of a string to lowercase. example:

```
bool equals(string status, string userInput)
{
    //lowercaseStatus = convert userInput to lowercase
    //lowercaseUserInput = convert status to lowercase
    return lowercaseStutus == lowercaseUserInput;
}
```

Then use the function in for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

if (equals(positive[i],reply))
{
        cout << "I am glad to hear that!" << endl;
}

else if (equals(negative[i],reply))
{
    cout << "I am sorry to hear that." << endl;
}
```